# Is it possible to mix writing an EF Core query with LINQ and a dynamic string query?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I was hoping to be able to write most of the query in LINQ, but then write the `WHERE` clause as a string, like you would a dynamic query. So something like:

`var query = from part in _context.CurrentInventory`

`query.Where = "part.PartNumber LIKE '%a%' OR part.PartNumber LIKE '%b%'`

The reason is because the WHERE can get quite large and using `EF.Functions.Like` and `Contains` really slows down the query.

I could build the whole thing dynamically and just execute the string, but I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: If you're worried about performance for that query, you can always fallback to ADO.NET or uses something like dapper. Or you can create stored procedures, Views w/e your fit your requirement. The way I usually set up my project is to use dapper for complex queries and EF for commands.

Comment: @12seconds Thanks. I'll try dapper and see if it works for something like this. I love EF. So it's a shame it has problems with something so small like this.

Comment: What's the problem with `EF.Functions.Like`?

Comment: @IvanStoev It takes forever to build the WHERE part of the query. Like 3-4 seconds, before the query even executes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [System.Linq.Dynamic](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)   which is  [based on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/bb894665.aspx) previous work

```
    Install-Package System.Linq.Dynamic
```

The query

```
   query.Where = "part.PartNumber LIKE '%a%' OR part.PartNumber LIKE '%b%'
```

can be re-written as:

```
    query.Where ("part.PartNumber.Contains(@0) or part.PartNumber.Contains(@1)","a" ,"b")
```

Working example at [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Wg7d8c)

**Update:**

I used dynamic Linq with EntityFramework

```
      using (var context = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            var customers = context.Customers.Where("ContactName.Contains(@0) or ContactName.Contains(@1)", "Maria","Carine").ToList();
            Console.WriteLine(customers.Count);
        }
```

The generated Sql (as seen from sql profiler) is:

```
    SELECT 
        [Extent1].[CustomerID] AS [CustomerID], 
        [Extent1].[CompanyName] AS [CompanyName], 
        [Extent1].[ContactName] AS [ContactName], 
        [Extent1].[ContactTitle] AS [ContactTitle], 
        [Extent1].[Address] AS [Address], 
        [Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
        [Extent1].[Region] AS [Region], 
        [Extent1].[PostalCode] AS [PostalCode], 
        [Extent1].[Country] AS [Country], 
        [Extent1].[Phone] AS [Phone], 
        [Extent1].[Fax] AS [Fax]
        FROM [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent1]
     WHERE ([Extent1].[ContactName] LIKE N'%Maria%') OR ([Extent1].[ContactName] LIKE N'%Carine%')
```

The where condition is translated to:

```
     WHERE ([Extent1].[ContactName] LIKE N'%Maria%') OR ([Extent1].[ContactName] LIKE N'%Carine%')
```

Comment: Ah. That looks like *exactly* what I'm looking for. I'll give it a try. Thanks for the suggestion.